# Type for React useRef targeting a scroll

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a useRef targeting a div to access the scroll property. What type will be it for a scroll.

**code:**

```
const scrollRef = useRef<any>(null);

const onClickScroll = (scrollOffset: any) => {
    scrollRef.current.scrollLeft += scrollOffset;
  };

//some code

return(

<div className={styles.book__container} ref={scrollRef}>
//some code
</div>
)
```

I tried using  but doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
const scrollRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

If you don't know what is the type, you can hover the `ref`

[image]

Comment: Hover the ref dint help as it shows `MutableRefObject<any>`

Comment: Do you use vscode? Maybe because you didn't install an extension. Try to install `Babel JavaScript`

Answer (score 2):

`HTMLDivElement | null` it seems:

```
const scrollRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
```

You might also want to use only `HTMLDivElement` so you don't have to spam `!` everywhere.

Comment: using only HTMLDivElement, then what will be my initial ref?